# how can get values from va-select when user choose the data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

how can get values from va-select when user choose the data?

I use this method to show my data in va-select

```
<va-select
:label="$t('Unit Code')"
v-model="aircraftData.afta_ProcUnit1"
textBy="name"
searchable
:options="optionsProcUnit1"
:addBtn="true"
placeholder=""
:error="!!afta_ProcUnit1Errors.length"
:error-messages="afta_ProcUnit1Errors"
/>

apiRelatedUnit(postData) {
      let self = this;
      this.isLoading = true;
      SmsApis.relatedUnit.post
        .GetRelatedUnit(postData)
        .then((xhr) => {
          self.isLoading = false;
          if (xhr.data.result[0].smsB_RelatedUnit) {
            xhr.data.result[0].smsB_RelatedUnit.forEach(function (g, i) {
                if (g.runt_Category === "0") {
                  self.optionsProcUnit2.push({
                    id: g.runt_unitID,
                    name: g.runt_unitID + " / " + g.runt_UnitTitle,
                    tel: g.runt_UnitTel,
                  });
                }
              if (g.runt_Category === "2") {
                self.optionsProcUnit1.push({
                  id: g.runt_unitID,
                  name: g.runt_unitID + " / " + g.runt_UnitTitle,
                  tel: g.runt_UnitTel,
                });
              }
            });
          } else {
            self.$swal.fire("Error", xhr.data.result[0].Error, "error");
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          self.isLoading = false;
          if (error.message === "Cannot read property 'status' of undefined")
            self.$swal.fire("Connect Error", "", "warning");
        });
    },
```

And the va-select will show like this one

```
Test / Sales 
Test2 / Dev
Test3 / Bus
```

and when user click submit, it's will send date and writing in database

```
pdbt = {
   tableA: [
            {
              afta_ProcUnit1: xxx, //how can get unit code in here???
              afta_ProcUnit2: ProcUnit2, 
            }
           ]
        }
Apis.AircraftAnomaly.post
          .EditAircraftAnomaly(pdbt )
          .then(function (xhr) {
            self.isLoading = false;
            if (xhr.data.result[0].Result === "OK") {
              self.onEditAnomalyCL();
              self.isLoading = true;
            } 
          })
      }
```

how can get value when user choose the options in va-select?